# Problems Rotating an object in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

I can't figure out why my drawing won't rotate properly. I've looked at many other examples looking to accomplish the same thing I am but nothing I have tried has worked. For some reason it's getting translated to another position unless I start the center at 0,0 and then it works perfectly.

```
void drawBolt(Point p, GLfloat rotation){
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(p.x, p.y,.0f);
    glRotatef(rotation,0,0,1);
    int pointArray[] = {
        p.x - 7, p.y + 10,
        p.x + 7, p.y + 10,
        p.x + 4, p.y + 2,
        p.x + 6, p.y + 2,
        p.x + 1, p.y - 5,
        p.x + 3, p.y - 5,
        p.x - 1, p.y - 12,
        p.x - 3, p.y - 5,
        p.x - 4, p.y - 5,
        p.x - 2, p.y + 2,
        p.x - 5, p.y + 2,
        p.x - 4, p.y + 13,
        p.x - 7, p.y + 14
    };
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    for(int i  = 0; i < 22; i++){
        glVertex2i(pointArray[i] * 2, pointArray[i + 1] * 2);
        i++;
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
}

void myDisplay()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Point a(50, 50);
    drawBolt(a, 180.0f);

}
```

Comment: Why are you applying a glTranslate and then do the same translation thing again, per element on your vertex positions? That's probably part of the reason you're seeing this.

Comment: sorry I'm a beginner with opengl. what exactly am I doing wrong? If its the way the code is written to draw the bolt then I'm lost about what to do. In my graphics class this is the only way I've been taught and I'm struggling with the examples online

Comment: @anthonyPorter: Hint: `glTranslatef( P.X, P.Y, …)` and later on `P.X + …, P.Y + …`. Also you should not use `glBegin`, `glVertex`, `glEnd`. They're deprecated for well over 15 years and have been removed in entirety from OpenGL-3 and later. If you want to learn modern OpenGL, use a modern tutorial like found at http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut

Comment: @datenwolf thanks I will get to reading. Is there any benefit of learning graphics in the old way it was used? Or is my instructor just wasting my time? And I didn't think I was translating anything with the P.x +... I was making an array of ints to be used as points. I understand that this is not the way to handle this however and I will start going through the tutorial. thanks again

Comment: @anthonyPorter: For about a decade all GPUs sold are of the programmable kind. Since 2006 shader model 3 has become the standard. Which essentially means you'll hardly find a fixed function GPU in anything that doesn't belong into a museum. There are sill boxes out there with FFP GPUs in them, but those are either in industrial control or run by computer inept people who don't care to update or run current software. So except if your goal is to port old, legacy software to modern OpenGL (for which you require knowledge about the FFP of course), yes your instructor *is* wasting your time.

Comment: @anthonyPorter: Also take note that modern, programmable pipeline OpenGL is a lot easier to use than FFP. In FFP you had an almost unsurmountable plethora of state switches, you'd have to keep in your mind. And to gain a certain result/effect you had to figure out a (often clever) way to connect the hardwired parts of fixed function pipeline. You could even do water ripple simulation and texture controlled pseudo-refraction with the FFP, but it was very hard work. With shaders you just write down what you want in a few lines of code and are done with.

Comment: After going through the first part of the tutorial I tried to implement the methods they were using to find that the lib files for glew aren't installed on our school computers. So I am forced to use the old methods. Any help?